# Can monads do what this OOP can't?

Tags: python, oop, monads

Trying to understand monads and wondering if they'd be useful for data transformation programming in Python, I looked at many introductory explanations. But I don't understand why monads are important.

Is the following Python code a good representation of the Maybe monad?

```
class Some:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val=val

    def apply(self, func):
        return func(self.val)


class Error:
    def apply(self, func):
        return Error()


a = Some(1)
b = a.apply(lambda x:Some(x+5))
```

Can you give an example of a monad solution, which cannot be transformed into such OOP code?

(Do you think monads for data transformation in OOP languages can be useful?)

Comment: Monads are used for functional programming, in many cases to denote some sort of sequence.

Comment: What you have is not equivalent to a monad solution. In a monad solution, the func parameter in apply would not have to return a monad object.

Comment: @DanielT.. I think I saw both versions. I could change it, but still the question is where there is more to monads.

Comment: As you can see from my answer below, not really. The reason Monads were introduced in Haskell was to force methods to execute in a programmer defined sequence (in Haskell, normally the compiler decides what order to execute functions in.) In other languages they operate more as a kind of adapter. Monads aren't rocket science, and even if they were, rocket science isn't really that hard. :-)

Comment: @DanielT.: So monads solve a problem that OO languages don't have? Given that the above OO solution is natural in Python, I do not need to learn monads for data transformations?

Comment: @Gerenuk I said that the reason they were introduced as to force execution order, that doesn't mean it's the only thing they are good for. A python array *is* a monad, you you need to understand monads to get full use out if it. And as what already pointed out to you, the code you have above is *not* a monad... It would be interesting to translate this article into python: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/828035/Monads/monads.pdf

Comment: I found this quote interesting: "Monads turn control flow into data flow, where it can be constrained but the type system." (Oleg Kiselyov)... Of course, type system constraints are something Python doesn't worry much about. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the article - it's more something I'm after. I'd like to be pragmatic and not care about definitions and naming. I only care about results. And if the OO solution is just as easy in Python, it wins. I may try to translate the article to Python. If it does fit into OO well enough, maybe monads is not something I need to worry about in non-functional languages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post that discusses monads using Swift as the language that might help you make more sense of them: http://www.javiersoto.me/post/106875422394

The basic point is that a monad is an object that has three components.

1. A constructor that can take some other object, or objects, and create a monad wrapping that object.
2. A method that can apply a function *that knows nothing about the monad* to its contents and return the result wrapped in a monad.
3. A method that can apply a function that takes the raw object and returns a result wrapped in the monad, and return that monad.

Note that this means even an Array class can be a monad if the language treats methods as first class objects, and the necessary methods exist.

If the language doesn't treat methods as first class objects, *even if it's an OO language*, it will not able able to implement Monads. I think your confusion may be coming from the fact that you are using a multi-paradigm language (Python) and assuming it is a pure OO language.

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` you've written corresponds to the monad function called `bind`.

Given that and the constructor `Some` (which for a generalized monad is called `unit` or `return`) you can define the functions `fmap` and `apply` which promote other kinds of functions: where `bind` promotes and uses a function that takes plain data and returns a monad, `fmap` does so for for functions from plain data to plain data, and `apply` does so for functions that are themselves wrapped inside the monad.

You would have issues, I think, defining the last monadic operation: `join`. `join` takes a nested monad and flattens it to a single layer.  So this is a method that can't be used on all objects of the class, only those with a particular structure.  And while `join` can be avoided if you define `bind` instead (you can write `join` in terms of `bind` and the identity function), it's inconvenient to define `bind` for array-like monads. Functions on arrays are more naturally described in terms of `fmap` (loop over the array and apply the function) and `join` (take a nested array and flatten it).

I think if you can attack these challenges, you can implement a monad in whatever language you choose.  And I do think that monads are useful in many languages, as many sub-computations can be described using them.  They represent a known solution to many common problems, and if they're already available to you, that means code you don't have to test or debug; they're tools that already work.

Implementing them yourself lets you use the functional literature and way of thinking to attack problems.  Whether that convenience is worth the effort of implementing them is up to you.